# How to share folder via ethernet cable to windows?

Tags: pi-3, ethernet, share

I am using my raspberry pi 3 in my college for a project. And I couldn't manage connect the raspberry pi to college network and unfortenetly IT doesn't help me about that issue.

So I manage to connect raspberry pi ssh via ethernet cable. However I want to see folders of rapsberry pi in my windows computer to share files fastly.

I was using samba in my home but it is not working with ethernet connection. How can I share folders of raspberry pi to windows with using ethernet? Or is it possible?

Comment: The Pi is a regular Linux computer.  You access the files as you would for any other Linux computer.  The question is not specific to the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Joan is right, but here's something for you to search for: [NFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_File_System), [Samba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samba_%28software%29).

Answer (score 2):

There are various programs that utilize SFTP, which is the file protocol that runs on the SSH port as well. Programs such as Filezilla, WinSCP, and others allow this type of connection. When using the program, input the IP of the Pi, and the username and password of your account when logging into SSH, and it will direct you to your /home/{user} directory or /root if you are logged in as root